# Do dns recursive queries affect on website performance?

Tags: domain-name-system

After checking my website dns in *intodns.com* I get the following errors:

```
Recursive queries: I could use the nameservers listed below to performe recursive queries. It may be that I am wrong but the chances of that are low. You should not have nameservers that allow recursive queries as this will allow almost anyone to use your nameservers and can cause problems. Problem record(s) are: 
130.xx.xx.128
```

AND

```
ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are: 
128.xx.xx.130.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips
```

Do these errors cause any problem or affect on website performance?

Answer (score 1):

As per Sven's post.
The lack of the PTR record will only affect recipients who's domains perform sender domain validity checks et al, which is by all accounts most domains these days.
Turn off the recursive DNS, you are leaving yourself wide open. 
As for website performance, shouldn't be an issue. The issues above relate to sending mail, and public use of your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

If you really run a DNS server on your machine and allow anyone recursive queries, you are an easy target for a DOS attack. Turn it off if is not necessary.

The missing PTR record will mainly affect your ability to reliably send mail. You will find that you can't do this.